# The light component is behind Image in Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, canvas, 2d-games, light

I have two different canvases: one for the background and one for the game scene

Principal canvas:
[image]

Background canvas:
[image]

I'm having this problem: If I put an object in the principal canvas, everything seems to works but If I add a light component to this object, I'll not see the light (it is like the background image is ahead the light):

Without the background canvas:
[image: without background]

With the background canvas:
[image: with bg canvas]

Any idea why?

(The problem is not the BGcanvas, the problem is the image component of the BGcanvas, if I disable it, I can see the light)

Answer (score 0):

## Lights are 3D scene objects

UI objects are not effected by lights or scene objects because they exist in a completely different rendering path:

[image: Screen space canvas]