# Calling my background Sprite to fill screen in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, screen-size, gameobject

I know that there are many questions like this on the net but I haven't found a solution to my problem yet...

I'm trying to make a background image that fills the screen. In my game, there is a canvas and inside this Canvas there is a gameObject which has attached the sprite component.

Many solutions includes this code:

```
void Awake()
{
    SpriteRenderer sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    if (sr == null) return;

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

    float width = sr.sprite.bounds.size.x;
    float height = sr.sprite.bounds.size.y;

    double variable = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 4.0;
    float worldScreenHeight = (float)variable;
    float worldScreenWidth = worldScreenHeight / Screen.height * Screen.width;

    transform.localScale = new Vector2(worldScreenWidth / width, worldScreenHeight / height);
}
```

But I tried it and it makes the gameobject really small.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't use UI Image instead of sprite inside canvas?

Comment: I tried this way but I was having another kind of problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016176/the-light-component-is-behind-image-in-unity

Comment: Ok; I edited your code and will post you the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, select your Canvas game object. in `Canvas Scaler` component set `UI Scale Mode` to `Constant Pixel Size`.

[image]

Note that, when you set `UI Scale Mode` to `Scale With Screen Size`, your image changes by screen width or height.

Also, Note that your image should be in the center of its parent. Set the transform position and rotation of your image to this:

[image]

Now Change your code to this:

```
void Awake()
{
    SpriteRenderer sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    if (sr == null) return;

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

    float width = sr.sprite.bounds.size.x;
    float height = sr.sprite.bounds.size.y;

    transform.localScale = new Vector2(Screen.width / width, Screen.height / height);
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I think that now it is perfectly the half of the screen size: https://i.imgur.com/QAaKylC.png

Comment: No, it isn't exactly the half because I tried this code: 
transform.localScale = new Vector2((Screen.width / width), Screen.height / height);
And the image isn't filling the screen

Comment: Is there a method to get the width and height of the canvas?

Comment: Is image filling the screen now?

Comment: Yeah. if you want to get width or height of canvas you can use this code in Canvas: `GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width`

Comment: Yes I have just found this on the net but I don't know how to SET the width and height of the gameobject

Comment: Please see `Canvas Scaler` component in your Canvas game object. is the `Scale Factor = 1`?

Comment: I'm using the option "Scale with screen size"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178737/discussion-between-ehsan-mohammadi-and-jr-antonio).

Comment: Yes it works thank you! but I'm having the same problem of before: Every object are ahead the background except the light component, I know that I would make anothe post but, any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome :) I saw your question about the light component, but I don't have any idea now. If I found a solution, post it to you :)

Comment: No problem my friend :)